# MVC custom membership could not load type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have created MVC project with default template structure in VB.NET.
I wrote custom membership provider which connects to SQL database.
In my web.config I added membership section.

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>

      <add name="MyName" type="MyMembershipProvider"
                connectionStringName="connName"
                enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
                enablePasswordReset="true"
                requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
                requiresUniqueEmail="false"
                maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
                minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
                minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
                passwordAttemptWindow="10"
                applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

After I fire up project and try to log on code breaks on AccountModels.vb, line 169 and points me to web.config provider section line.

```
  Public Sub New(ByVal provider As MembershipProvider)
    _provider = If(provider, Membership.Provider)
  End Sub
```

Because I have VS2010 and VS2013 I tried MVC2 and MVC4 and same thing happens.

Comment: what does the exception says?

Comment: Pretty sure you need to specify the assembly where the type is located, something like this `type="MyMembershipProvider, MyAssembly"`

Comment: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled by user code
  BareMessage=Could not load type 'MyMembershipProvider'.
  Filename=Path\web.config
  HResult=-2146232062
  Line=41
  Message=Could not load type 'MyMembershipProvider'. Path\web.config line 41)
  Source=System.Web
  StackTrace:
       ...

Comment: MyMembershipProvider is located in App_Data folder. It's an ordinary class which inherits MembershipProvider. Also, if I use default provider everything works fine.

Comment: @Willow And what is the namespace of the project?

Comment: @David Root namespace is Test2. I tried with Test2.MyMembershipProvider in providers section and in defaultProvider attribute and then it tells me that it can be found.